# What is it that allows a thing to be triggered?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

If I step in a bear trap and get caught, I triggered the trap by stepping in it. The trap being set made it something that could be triggered. Both the trap and my stepping in it are causes of me getting caught. What word complements "trigger" to describe the kind of cause that is setting the trap?

<s>If I lose money on a horse race, my horse coming in 2nd is one cause of my loss. Having placed a bet on the race is another cause. I only lost money because of both of these causes combined.</s>

The horse losing the race is the *trigger*. What word complements "trigger" to describe the kind of cause that is having placed the bet?

Sample sentence: *When looking into an incident, the trigger is often clear, but the more important cause is usually the __________.*

I'm especially looking to use this term in the world of business and technology. Examples I'd like to describe:

- I lost my data because my hard drive failed and I kept only a single copy of my data. The hard drive failure was the trigger. Keeping only a single copy was the other kind of cause.
- An employee left the company because they found a good offer and because they were dissatisfied with their working conditions.
- The company defaulted on the contract because they delivered in six months but had promised to deliver in three.
- The computer was infected because the user opened a phishing attachment and the computer's anti-virus had been disabled.

I feel like there has to be a technical term for this from medicine or engineering even if there isn't one in common parlance, but my Google abilities are failing me.

Engineering example: *The building collapse was triggered by the high winds striking the corner of the building, where the dampeners had only been designed for head-on winds.*

Medical example: *The bee sting triggered the patient's allergy.*

What kind of cause are the design failure and allergy?

Comment: Something like the *critereon* for failure? Prerequisite? I don't see how one is necessarily *the* trigger, just because it happened to be the last requirement met. I could bet with my friend on something in the past, and then go investigate who won. Does that change the trigger? Or is this some terminology used in logical analysis?

Comment: Maybe I should provide a medical or engineering example, because the difference seems clearer to me than simply "what happened second," unless we're doubting causality altogether.

Comment: These are often called “contributing factors”

Comment: Why is _the horse losing the race_ the 'trigger', rather than your placing the bet? Because it happens later? If so, pre-existing contributory factors would be 'predispositions' in the medical examples.

Comment: @Davo In many cases, there is a latent element which makes the sufferer susceptible to potential harm if something changes to contribute with the latent element. It makes sense that the _trigger_ is the thing that has to change, while the latent element isn’t. The horse-racing example isn’t the best; it’s clearer in the engineering example: the design of the dampeners is constant and doesn’t change—doesn’t trigger anything in itself. It’s the _change_ in the wind direction that causes the unfortunate combination.

Comment: Perhaps the bear-trap example is better than the horse race? Y'all are welcome to write up your suggestions as answers, although none of them strike me as quite right, although "latent cause" is promising and seems to have some hits online.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation

Comment: Are you looking for something with a similar meaning to *root cause*?

Comment: Ed beat me to it, but their are simple tests in law to discriminate between those two types of cause. If they don't seem to work, you should probably look for a term other than cause, because those tests have been in place for centuries.

Comment: Why are y'all guessing and discussing in comments? Post your answers and vote on the best.

Comment: Several of the people commenting are probably doing so because they suggested a phrase rather than a single word. If you're fine with that, then you should update the tags on the question accordingly.

Comment: @Alok - I've added tags in an attempt to show that I want the most precise and concise way to refer to these, but that I'm am not a stickler for keeping it to a single word.

Comment: A: The thing has a trigger, B: there is no trigger lock installed, and C: the safety is off.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_cause

Answer (score 3):

I really think you’re overcomplicating something that doesn’t need it.

Trigger first applied to a crossbow and now fits a firearm, and with either there’s first a trigger then a finger then a shooter then a commander then a patron and how far will you go for a real cause, please?

In your trap analogy what really complements *trigger* is your own *setting* but that’s not what you want, is it? Nor is any physical part of the trapper.

Does that not leave you with the trapper’s or his boss’s plan/intention/aim/desire?

In your examples I suggest the hard drive failure was not the trigger, but the result. A soft- or hardware fault, a power surge, a coffee spill or some such was the trigger and importantly, Keeping only a single copy was irrelevant, on the level of your Question.

Ignoring employees leaving and companies defaulting and computers being infected, you’re really asking *What kind of cause are the design failure and allergy*, aren’t you?

They’re *underlying* causes.

The *underlying* cause of a bear-trap being set is prolly the fur market.

The *underlying* cause of your data loss might have been a power surge which triggered the HD failure.

The *underlying* cause of your building collapsing was a design flaw which failed to take account of strong winds, which triggered the collapse.

The *underlying* cause of the bee-sting problem was the allergy, which meant that the bee-sting triggered the appropriate response.

Comment: I think you're getting at something important, but your causal chain for the trigger-pulling isn't what I'm asking about. Pulling the trigger on a crossbow is not a sufficient cause; the crossbow must also be cocked. A cocked crossbow is triggerable. An uncocked crossbow is not. If I ask, "why did the crossbow fire?" one answer is that you pulled the trigger, but another answer is that it was cocked. This becomes a more interesting distinction when someone pulls the trigger on a gun, thinking they are dry-firing it, but someone else had loaded the gun without their knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, Dane, and suffice it to say that because the bolt sitting on the outside of a crossbow is visible and the bullet inside a gun isn't, doesn't make any linguistic difference; not grammatically nor semantically. 

Beyond that thanks, and I try to avoid pin-dancing…

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the following words:

> [Juncture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juncture)
>
> *a point of time at this juncture; especially :  one made critical by a concurrence of circumstances*

and,

> [Rubicon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Rubicon)
>
> *a bounding or limiting line; especially :  one that when crossed commits a person irrevocably*

and,

> [Pivotal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivotal)
>
> 1:  of, relating to, or constituting a [pivot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot)
>
> 2:  vitally
>   important :  [critical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical)

A pivot is: *a person, thing, or factor having a major or central role, function, or effect*. So in this case at a given Juncture (time oriented) you identified a Pivot (thing oriented). The Pivot is, therefore, Pivotal.

**EDIT**:

The words I've proposed were based on the request by the OP:

> I'm especially looking to use this term in the world of business and
>   technology.

I do feel its specially consistent with the OP intentions because you find them regularly in Business and Tech articles:

> When the iPod wheel was ruled out and the touch ruled in, the new
>   question was how to build the phone’s operating system. This was a
>   **critical juncture** — it would determine whether the iPhone would be positioned as an accessory or as a mobile computer. ([link](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/13/15782200/one-device-secret-history-iphone-brian-merchant-book-excerpt))
>
> Perhaps the most **pivotal** couplings were the ones that turbocharged
>   complex, or eukaryotic, cells. Eukaryotes use specialised organelles
>   such as mitochondria and chloroplasts to extract energy from food or
>   sunlight. ([link](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn9951-top-10-lifes-greatest-inventions/))
>
> "Somewhere between the janitor and the CEO, reasons stop mattering,"
>   says Jobs, adding, that **Rubicon** is "crossed when you become a VP."
>   ([link](http://www.businessinsider.fr/us/steve-jobs-on-the-difference-between-a-vice-president-and-a-janitor-2011-5/))

Comment: Uh… no. Junctures, rubicons and pivots have no place here.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I just added multiple links to articles of well know media, using those exact words, in the context the OP requested. Although I don't mind some constructive criticism I do find a condescending attitude something specially belittle to what is supposed to be the objective of communities like this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, discussions, and my own research, the best I've found are the following options.

> [Potential](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potential#Noun)
>
> 1. Currently unrealized ability
> 2. (physics) . . .
> 3. (physics) . . .
> 4. (grammar) A verbal construction or form stating something is possible or probable.

This can be used to describe the *trigger of* and *potential for* a given effect. For example, a cocked crossbow has the *potential* to fire a bolt, and depressing the lever *triggers* this potential.

Related, where you might want to be quite clear that you are talking about having potential, rather than being uncertain (such as when you say that excess sugar is a "possible cause" of hyperactivity), then you might want the following:

> [Potentiality](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potentiality#Noun)
>
> 1. The quality of being, or having potential.
> 2. An inherent capacity for growth or development.
> 3. An aptitude amenable to development; capability.

This may even be the best term to use in the sample sentence:
*When looking into an incident, the **trigger** is often clear, but the more important cause is usually the **potentiality**.*

While [proximate and ultimate causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation) relate to this, the cause that allows something to be triggered seems to be a second *proximate cause* and better described in terms of [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) as above.

While searching for various kinds of causes, one that seems to be an accurate description is a ***latent cause***.

> [Latent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latent#Adjective)
>
> Existing or present but concealed or inactive.

This adjective might be combined with *proximate* to speak about a *latent proximate cause* and a *triggering proximate cause*. Where I want to emphasize the latent cause over the trigger, I might say, "the latent cause and its triggering event."

Finally, the words *condition* and *contingency* seem like they may apply to some examples, where a *contingency* may be *triggered* or something may be a *condition* for a *trigger* to bring about the effect.

Comment: Hmm I disagree with *potential*, but from that I think you want something like *enabling cause* - the fact that A was the only reason cause B could happen at all.

Answer (score -2):

[origin](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/origin) could be used if you want a **single word** specifically. I would also suggest *proximate cause* for the condition that finally results in the event (getting caught by the trap).

> I lost my data because my hard drive failed and I kept only a single copy of my data. The hard drive failure was the trigger.

The **origin** was only keeping a single copy of my data, and the **proximate** cause of data loss was hard drive failure.

Given the new clarification that it doesn't need to be a single word, then most of the appropriate answers will be of the form `xyz clause` - such as *root cause* suggested in a comment; or *original cause* (clearer than just saying origin) which however isn't as good fit as the others :)

If you don't consider the trap being set up as *more important* than it getting triggered, then you can also call it a [**conditional clause**](http://media.acc.qcc.cuny.edu/faculty/volchok/causalMR/CausalMR3.html) which was *necessary but not sufficient* for getting caught in the trap.  Both of these (*setting trap* + *stepping on it*) together are the [**independent sufficient causes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causation_(law)#Independent_sufficient_causes) for the result to take place.

Comment: No, the actual cause of data loss was whatever made the HD fail. Origin is simply not an appropriate term grammatically, semantically or in any way idiomatically.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Fire investigations are actually called 'origin & cause' investigations. In context of OP, it could be stated as *The destruction was caused by fire (trigger), but the more important reason was the origin* imho. Also, note that OP asked for a SWR not a phrase which limits the possible answers.

Comment: Really? First, what's an SWR?

Fire investigations can be called whatever they like in the jurisdictions you're familiar with and why would that make that terminology applicable generally?

I talked to fire officers most working days for years and I never once heard the phrase *origin & cause*. What does that tell you, please?

Even if the conclusion *The destruction was caused by fire (trigger)* isn't your own guess, it would clearly apply to every single fire, making itself meaningless.

Further, *trigger* relates how to *origin or cause*?

Comment: SWR - single word request. Yes, fire being trigger would apply always, I was trying to fit in a sentence similar to the sample sentence in question.

Comment: Oh… single word request and first, I saw nothing of that in the Question and further, have you noticed that most SWR can't be answered as such, but need phrases instead of words?

None of which alters the simple fact that what best fits the OQ is *underlying* until you can justify a better option.

Comment: SWR is the only tag, hard to miss :) ... as is the 'sample sentence' which you can search for if you didn't read entire OP. *underlying* is as good as *root* that was suggested in a comment earlier, but doesn't really work without *cause* next to it. Though, since the poster has commented on your answer without a clarification it does seem he doesn't know what is SWR tag for, in which case *underlying cause* is good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63944/discussion-between-alok-and-robbie-goodwin).